# Why can't Bill Pay payments be scheduled with savings accounts with some banks?

Tags: online-payment, savings-account

Why can't [Bill Pay payments](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/online-bill-pay-what-it-is-why-you-should-use-it/) be scheduled with savings accounts with some banks?

For example, the Bill Pay at bank of America doesn't the users to schedule payments with saving accounts:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the United States to be considered a savings account the number of monthly transaction is supposed to be 6 or fewer. This is covered in [Federal Regulation D](https://www.federalreserve.gov/boarddocs/supmanual/cch/int_depos.pdf).

> allow no more than six transfers or withdrawals per calendar month or
>   statement cycle of at least four weeks for the purpose of transferring
>   funds to another of the depositor’s accounts at the same institution
>   or making third-party payments by means of preauthorized, automatic,
>   or telephonic transfers or transfers or withdrawals made by check,
>   debit card, or other similar order made by the depositor and payable
>   to third parties

The bank can then have a policy to disallow connecting a savings account to an automatic payment system. They generally don't allow paychecks to be direct deposited into a savings account.  They generally don't allow automatic payments from the savings account.

If you exceed the 6 transfers, they may charge a fee. Or if you do it too many months in a row, they can convert the account to a checking account.